# cvCreateFileCapture strange error

Tags: c, opencv, video-capture, samba

i'm trying to create a simple Opencv program in C that creates a file capture from a .avi, and it plays it in a window highlighting faces. I'm running a self-compiled version of Opencv (i already tried the same with a jpeg image and it works).

Building goes well, no errors, no warning, but when i launch it this the console output this:

Unknown parameter encountered: "server role"
Ignoring unknown parameter "server role"

And the program simply stops

Previously it was complaining for a missing /home/#user/.smb/smb.conf file, so i tried installing samba ( even though i've still no idea what does samba have to do in all this )

here is my code:

main(){

```
    printf("Ciao!");

    cvNamedWindow("window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    cvWaitKey(0);

    printf("ok");

    CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture("monsters.avi");


    CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade = load_object_detector("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");

    CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

    //List of the faces
    CvSeq* faces;

    while (0<10) {
        CvArr* image = cvQueryFrame(capture);


        double scale = 1;

        faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(image,cascade, storage, 1.2, 2, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, cvSize(1,1), cvSize(300,300));

        int i;

        for(i = 0; i < faces->total; i++ )
            {

                CvRect face_rect = *(CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem( faces, i );
                cvRectangle( image,
                            cvPoint(face_rect.x*scale,face_rect.y*scale),
                            cvPoint((face_rect.x+face_rect.width)*scale,(face_rect.y+face_rect.height)*scale),
                            CV_RGB(255,0,0) , 3, 8, 0);
            }

        cvReleaseMemStorage( &storage );

        cvShowImage("window", image);
    }

    cvWaitKey(0);

    printf("Ciao!");
```

}

---

I thank you for your answer, i switched to C++ for my trials. Now i did this:

```
int main(){
namedWindow("Video", CV_WINDOW_FREERATIO);

VideoCapture cap("sintel.mp4");
 if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;

Mat edges;
for(;;){


    Mat frame;
    cap>>frame;
    cvtColor(frame, edges, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    GaussianBlur(edges, edges, Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
    Canny(edges, edges, 0, 30, 3);

    imshow("Video", edges);
    //cvWaitKey(0);

}


return(0);
}
```

Now it succesfully load the video and query a frame, evry time i press a key it obviously query another frame and everything works fine, but if i comment the waitkey() the program simply hangs for a bit and crashes if i try to close the window, i'm starting to think there is a problem with codecs or something like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works fine, i changed cvWaitKey() with this

```
   if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
```

I don't understand exactly why but now everything works as it should :)

Answer (score 0):

There are **so many potential problems** in the code, most of them related to not coding defensively.

What is `cvWaitKey(0);` doing after `cvNamedWindow()`? It's unecessary, remove it!

What happens if the capture was unsucessful? Code defensively:

CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture("monsters.avi");
if (!capture)
{
   // File not found, handle error and possibly quit the application
}

and you should use this technique for every pointer that you receive from OpenCV, ok?

One of the major problems, is that you allocate memory for `CvMemStorage` before the loop, but inside the loop you release it, which means that after the first loop iteration there will be no longer a valid `CvMemStorage* storage`, and that's a HUGE problem.

Either move the allocation procedure to the beginning of the loop, so on every iteration memory is allocated/deallocated, or move the `cvReleaseMemStorage( &storage );` call out of the loop.